# Proving a goal with an existential quantifier and making sure it covers all cases

Tags: proof-verification

I'm trying to prove the following theorem:

> Suppose x is a real number. Prove that if x $\neq$ 1 then there is a
>   real number y such that $\frac{y + 1}{y - 2}$ = x.

The logical structure of the sentence is:

x $\neq$ 1 $\implies$ $\exists$y($\frac{y + 1}{y - 2}$ = x)

I first suppose x $\neq$ 1 so my goal becomes $\exists$y($\frac{y + 1}{y - 2}$ = x).

[How to Prove it: A Structured Approach](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521675995) says the following regarding goals with existential quantifiers:

> To prove a goal of the form $\exists$x P(x): Try to find a value of x
>   for which you think P(x) will be true. Then start your proof with “Let
>   x = (the value you decided on)” and proceed to prove P(x) for this
>   value of x.

Let's say I chose y = 5. I can therefore let y = 5, conclude that $\frac{y + 1}{y - 2}$ = 2, and since my hypotheses say x $\neq$ 1 and 2 $\neq$ 1 finish my proof.

However this looks like I'm proving a theorem about a certain value of x instead or proving the theorem for all values of x except for 1. I feel I'm proving the following instead:

"Prove that if x = 2 then there is a real number y such that $\frac{y + 1}{y - 2}$ = x"

How should I deal with goals with existential quantifiers instead, to make sure I prove all the cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should solve for $y$ in terms of $x$. Once you find it, you can then go back and choose $y$ to be this number and show that it works. Messing around, we see that:
\begin{align*}
\frac{y + 1}{y - 2} &= x \\
y + 1 &= xy - 2x \\
2x + 1 &= xy - y = y(x - 1) \\
y &= \frac{2x + 1}{x - 1}
\end{align*}
We're now ready to prove what we want.

---

**Proof:** Suppose that $x \neq 1$. Then consider $y = \frac{2x + 1}{x - 1}$ (which is a well-defined real number, since we're not dividing by zero). Observe that:
\begin{align*}
\frac{y + 1}{y - 2}
&= \frac{\frac{2x + 1}{x - 1} + 1}{\frac{2x + 1}{x - 1} - 2} \\
&= \frac{(2x + 1) + (x - 1)}{(2x + 1) - 2(x - 1)} \\
&= \frac{(2x + 1) + (x - 1)}{(2x + 1) + (-2x + 2)} \\
&= \frac{3x}{3} \\
&= x
\end{align*}
as desired. $~~\blacksquare$

Comment: Alternatively just note that the statements in the first part are all equivalent.